# HTTP 401 exception while using GET method of JIRA REST API from Java Code

Tags: java, jira-rest-api

I am trying to consume JIRA API with java code. It is giving me 401. This error states that

```
HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

But the link and credentials which I am using in the code are working perfectly fine with Firefox REST Client.It is driving me crazy. Here is my code.

```
    String url = "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/1/search?jql=project=APS";
    URL obj = new URL(url);

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //Setting the Request Method header as GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //Prepairing credentials        
    String cred= "ahmed.tausif@spmconsulting.net:spm12345678";
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(cred.getBytes());                     
    String credentials = new String(encoded);

    //Setting the Authorization Header as 'Basic' with the given credentials
    con.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);

    //Setting the User-Agent header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    //reading the return 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())
            );
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    String result = response.toString();
```

I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/USER-274
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at jira_RESPAPI.getJSON(jira_RESPAPI.java:53)
    at connector.main(connector.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/USER-274
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at jira_RESPAPI.getJSON(jira_RESPAPI.java:49)
```

Hours spent on this cant figure it out.

p.s. Also when I send a GET request through Firefox RESTClient the following box appears, clicking on it 5-7 times makes it disappear then I can see the result.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your exact same code (with some very minor changes) and it worked perfectly. From this I can only assume:

1. The creds you are providing are incorrect
2. You have a typo in your URL
3. Base64.encodeBase64 is returning something wrong.

Try using

```
java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(cred.getBytes())
```

instead

My whole code, for your reference:

```
    package hello;

    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.Base64;


    public class Application {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            String url = "https://my-jira-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/MOON-13";
            URL obj = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            //Setting the Request Method header as GET
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            //Prepairing credentials
            String cred = "my@jira.com:mypassword";
            byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(cred.getBytes());
            String credentials = new String(encoded);

            //Setting the Authorization Header as 'Basic' with the given credentials
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);

            //Setting the User-Agent header
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT);

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

            //reading the return
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())
            );
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = response.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Somaiah, I figured out the problem, If I am using the API with trial account it wont accept creds. BUt otherwise it would.

Comment: That's strange. My code was also on the trial account, and it worked fine. But glad to know you got it working.